# Send Email Once All Items in Array Are The Same

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to write a simple VBA script that will send an email once specific cells in a spreadsheet are given a value of "Complete". I have created an array based on these cell values and can loop through the array just fine. The challenge I'm having is getting the code to only execute once and not the number of times the value "Complete" is found in the array.

I've included my code below:

```
    Dim arr(3) As String

    arr(0) = Range("A73").Value
    arr(1) = Range("A77").Value
    arr(2) = Range("A81").Value
    arr(3) = Range("A84").Value

    For Each i In arr
     If i = "Complete" Then
      Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
     End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need an `Exit For` so it exits the loop after the first find of `Complete`.

```
Dim arr(3) As String

arr(0) = Range("A73").Value
arr(1) = Range("A77").Value
arr(2) = Range("A81").Value
arr(3) = Range("A84").Value

Dim i As Variant
For Each i In arr
    If i = "Complete" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a variable with value 0 and if you find smth different of "complete" you set it to 1, when the foreach finishis you check the value.

```
Dim flag as String
flag = 0

For Each i In arr
     If i != "Complete" Then
      flag = 1
     End If
    Next i

if(flag==0){ Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook }
```

I havent code in vb since a long while, forgot de syntax but the idea is there.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I guess I just needed help working out the logic.

Comment: Note that this loop will run until the end even if "complete" is found once which is a wasting of time. You don't need a flag or anything you just need to add a `Exit For` into the OP's original code.